# Pin App on Wear OS, so a user only can interact with that app?

Tags: android, wear-os

we go on a trade fair and want to present our WearOS App there, so the user can interact with it. For safety reasons we would like to pin the app so that a user only can interact with our app and no other apps until this mode is deactivated (so a user for example can not uninstall the app). There are similar options for android smartphones and ios devices we already use, but i did not found such an option for wear os. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's no kiosk mode on WearOS, but you can make your app into "kiosk app", when a user leaves your app (`onPause`) it will relaunch your app: https://medium.com/@sanatshukla11/achieve-100-kiosk-mode-on-android-wear-10d71fa55997

Answer (score 0):

there is a kiosk mode if you use the samsung galaxy watch and are registered to use samsung knox (which is not easy but possible).
so i guess there is also a kiosk mode in other wear os watches as well, probably via google enterprise services (which is also not easy to get)